# Forum Current Online users

Tags: php, forum, yii2

I have my own forum script in PHP (Yii2 Actually) and I want to show online users.
It would be easy if users would be active up until they log out. But that is not the case. Most of the time user leave their machines logged in but they are not active. Here I could use time limit (renewing time with each request and deleting those which are past that time limit) but isn't that overkill?

Is there any popular/better way of monitoring online users in the forum?

Comment: How do you know someone has "left their machine logged in and not active" rather than reading a very long forum post? Or does that not matter? Would they be considered inactive?

Comment: after let say fifteen minutes of inactivity (not that each request user sends updates that he is active) will mark them inactive so other users (who are browsing) will not see the former user as active
Did I answer your question, please?

Comment: You did, thanks :) 2 ways you can go about it (from the top of my head). **1.** Have a countdown in JavaScript of 900 seconds to send an AJAX request to your server to mark the user as inactive. **2.** Update the users last action on every page request.

Comment: Well sounds great idea. I think I will go with this one if no better Idea is found. Thanks!

Comment: I think it qualify to be one of answers there and would be happy to upvote (and if no better idea accept it)

Comment: on 1. what about user with multiple pages open of different threads of same forum. Isn't there going to be racing i updates?

Comment: There would be yes, but what is the difference between that and someone refreshing the same thread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible way is to intercept user interface events in javascript and send an ajax notification to the server that the user is still there. Of course, this should be buffered, so that you don't get flooded with requests when the user moves the mouse. Something along the lines of

```
$('body').on('keydown mousemove scroll', function() {

     clearTimeout(notifyTimer);
     notifyTimer = setTimeout(function() {
           $.get('my-server.com/user-is-active');
     }, 60 * 1000);
});
```

On the server side, update the `last-active` field in the users table with the current timestamp. When displaying online users, select those with `last-active > now - 15 min`.

Comment: this one is brilliant too. Thanks!